# Como mudar o Status de um campo com Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos**, sou iniciante em asp.net MVC. Na minha aplicação eu tenho uma tela que o **Aluno** faz sua **Inscrição** em um curso, também tenho um campo **Quantidade de Vagas** e outro campo **Status** que diz se o curso está **Disponível** ou **Encerrado**, o que eu estou tentando fazer é: Quando minha **Quantidades de vagas** chegar a *zero* o **Status** do curso deve mudar para **Encerrado**. Não sei se com `javascript` seria a melhor maneira de se fazer isso. Do jeito que tentei tá errado e não dá certo. Alguém pode me ajudar?!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Minha View**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<style>
    #Status {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .encerrado {
        background-color: green;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

    .disponivel {
        background-color: orange;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

</style>

<h2>Catálogo de Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/Curso/Ementa?id=@item.Id">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                             {
                                 <a class="inscricao btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(), Alerta()">Inscrição</a>
                                 <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="inscricaoId" />
                             }
                            else
                            {
                                 <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("HomeAluno", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        function Status() {
            var st = document.getElementsByClassName("Status").value;

            if (st == document.getElementsByClassName("disponivel")) {
                return st;
            } else {
                return document.getElementsByClassName("encerrado");
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.Status').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "Curso Disponível") {
                    $(this).addClass("disponivel");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Encerrado") {
                    $(this).addClass("encerrado");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que tem uma falha de lógica nesse seu código, porque analisando seu `razor` você sempre usa o `item.Status`, então quer dizer que ele está sempre **Disponível**. Você precisa alterar seu código pra quando estiver com `0` vagas você altera o valor do seu `item.Status` para **Encerrado** e salva no banco.

Dessa forma quando você atualizar sua tela sempre vai pegar o `item.Status` correto.

Em último caso pode fazer algo assim:

```
<td>
    @if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0) 
    {
         <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="Curso Disponível" />
    } 
    else 
    {
         <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="Curso Encerrado" />
    }
</td>
```

Mas ainda acho errado desse jeito.

Comment: Teria uma outra forma @Maicon?

Comment: Como eu te disse, é só você atualizar o valor do campo no banco quando a quantidade chegar a 0, está fazendo isso?

Comment: Sim! Dessa forma aí serviu aqui pra mim... Vai dar pra usar por enquanto! Valeu!!!